# How to enable Multiple Downloads in Vba Selenium (Edge)

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm making a webscraping program, and in the same page I need to download multiple files.

But when I try to download the second file it pops up a message to allow multiple downloads.

I have already tried something like:

```
driver.SetPreference "download.default_directory", "C:\PDF_folder\"
driver.SetPreference "download.directory_upgrade", True
driver.SetPreference "download.prompt_for_download", False
```

But the **allow** window still appears. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow to download multiple files you need to add the following preference:

```
driver.SetPreference "profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads": 1
```

Comment: it didn't work, i tried adding
driver.SetPreference "profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads","":1" 
too but still with the same problem,

Comment: `1` stands for binary `true`

Comment: Nice, it worked, i used:
driver.SetPreference "profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1
Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Glad to be able to help you out.